# Retrieving normal looking Mathematica input from a cell expression

Tags: cells, input-forms

After a bad saving, I had problems with my *Mathematica* notebook. I have expressions in this form:

```
Cell[BoxData[
   RowBox[{
      RowBox[{"\[CapitalOmega]", 
         SuperscriptBox[
           RowBox[{"(", 
              RowBox[{"B\[Beta]", "|", "B\[Alpha]"}], ")"}], 
       "B\[Beta]"]}], "=", 
      RowBox[{"{", 
         RowBox[{"0", ",", 
            RowBox[{"D", "[", 
               RowBox[{
                  RowBox[{"\[Beta]", "[", "t", "]"}], ",", "t"}], 
          "]"}], ",", "0"}], 
         "}"}]}]], "Input",
  CellChangeTimes -> {{3.6538827264790764`*^9, 3.653882730240291*^9}, {
       3.653882768458477*^9, 
    3.653882777822013*^9}, {3.653883018977806*^9, 
       3.653883022469006*^9}, 
   3.653890453286024*^9, {3.6539033468457146`*^9, 
       3.653903357854344*^9}, {3.6539035195335913`*^9, 
    3.653903541642856*^9}, 
      3.653903623781554*^9}]
```

How can I retrieve normal looking *Mathematica* input from this kind of code?

Answer (score 5):

Works ok like this, without the cell change times.  I didn't change anything else.

Paste it into a notebook and choose 'interpret', or don't and prefix it with `CellPrint` to see the code.

```
Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{RowBox[{"\[CapitalOmega]",
      SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"(",
         RowBox[{"B\[Beta]", "|", "B\[Alpha]"}], ")"}], 
       "B\[Beta]"]}], "=", RowBox[{"{", RowBox[
       {"0", ",", RowBox[{"D", "[",
          RowBox[{RowBox[{"\[Beta]", "[", "t", "]"}],
            ",", "t"}], "]"}],
        ",", "0"}], "}"}]}]], "Input"]
```

Comment: Thank you perfect !
I manage with CellPrint. However, i didn't find 'interpret'. May you precise me its location ? Thank you

Comment: The option to interpret the text appears automatically when I paste it into a notebook.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is:

1. start a new input cell in your notebook by typing any character
2. select the cell by clicking on the cell bracket on the right-had side
3. choose Show Expression from the Cell menu
4. select the text of the now visible cell expression and paste your cell expression to replace it.
5. repeat steps 2 and 3

Show Expression has the shortcut <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on OS X. I think it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on Windows. Don't know what it is on other operating systems.

Comment: After step 4 you need to uncheck Show Expression.

Comment: @JackLaVigne. Repeating step 3 will accomplish that.